# How to calculate sum of Pi

Tags: c++, pi

I posted not long ago on how to compute the sum of Pi with openmp. But it seems something's off with my code. Because manually I get the right result, but when I program it, it gives wrong results, if someone can help me?

PS : s= 1/N

[image: Sum of pi]

```
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>

double f(double x)
{
  return (4 / (1 + (x * x)));
}

int main()
{
    int i;
    const int N = 60;
    double s1=0.0; double s2=0.0; double s3=0.0;
    double pi = 0.0; double s4=0.0; double s5=0.0;
    
    for (int i=0; i<N; i++)
        {
            //pi+=((f(i/N)+f((i+1)/N))/2*N);
            s1 = f(i/N);
            s2 = f((i+1)/N);
            s3 = 2 * N;
            s4 = s1 + s2;
            s5 = s4 / s3;
            pi+=s5;
        }
        
  printf("Pi = %f",pi);
  return 0; 
}
```

Comment: `i/N` for `i<N` is always the `int` `0`. You have to write `(double)i/N` or so.

Answer (score 2):

1. The reason the value is different is because variable 'i' as well as 'N' are int's. When dividing int by int the answer will always be int.

Easiest and fastest fix is to change one of the variables to a double eg.:

```cpp
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>

double f(double x)
{
  return (4 / (1 + (x * x)));
}

int main()
{
    const int N = 60;
    double s1=0.0; double s2=0.0; double s3=0.0;
    double pi = 0.0; double s4=0.0; double s5=0.0;

    for (double i=0; i<N; i++) // i changed the int to double for the 'i' declaration
        {
            //pi+=((f(i/N)+f((i+1)/N))/2*N);
            s1 = f(i/N);
            s2 = f((i+1)/N);
            s3 = 2 * N;
            s4 = s1 + s2;
            s5 = s4 / s3;
            pi+=s5;
        }

  //printf("Pi = %f",pi);
  std::cout << "Pi = " << pi << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

2. Also since you're programming in c++ make sure to pick the better c++ alternative to some of the code:

`printf` is C. It still works but c++'s `cout` is a better alternative that's improved and safer in most cases.

3. You also have an extra unneeded variable declaration. You're creating two 'i' variables. Once at the start and once in the loop.

Comment: You should never use a `double` as the loop variable. `double`s are not exact. It might be that in the last iteration the `double` value in `i` is a little bit smaller than the `int` value `N`, creating an additional iteration.

Comment: damn good to know. This was just meant to be an example of the easiest and fastest way to fix the problem. For this scope i don't think that it would actually matter but that's really good to know.

Answer (score 0):

As I got it from the answers, the problem was in (i/N). Since the i int declared as an int we need to add ((double)i/N).

```
pi+=((f((double)i/N)+f(((double)i+1)/N))/(2*N));
```

Comment: Such casting is concidered C. C++ casting: 'static_cast<toType>(var)'
Example:
static_cast<double>(i); //will cast int into double

Comment: C++ *is* closely related to C

Comment: C++ was created to be the combination of C and object oriented programming. Pretty much all C code can be compiled in c++. That being said not everything in C is ideal. The changed c++ makes to some C stuff helps you contain possible memory leaks on top of quite a bit of other security problems that arise when using some C code. Cout is a good example of this. Yes C code works in c++, that doesnt mean you should use that alternative over the c++ better option. In the end you're programming in c++ not C.